# Linking to Qt4 library

Tags: hyperlink, qt4, shared-libraries

I am trying to compile a short test program that requires Qt4, but have trouble properly linking to the Qt4 library. I have installed Qt4 via

sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools

The program code looks like this

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << "Qt version: " << qVersion() << std::endl;
}
```

The shared library libQtCore.so is at /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu but trying to compile the following way

g++ -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wall -o test.exe test.cpp -lQtCore

returns an error message that there is no file or directory called QtCore.

I have also tried to directly use the QtCore source code, but have received the following error message:

/tmp/ccljEHOY.o: In function `main':
test.cpp:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to`qVersion()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Ips

Answer (score 0):

The compiler was not able to find `QtCore` file because you need to add path with Qt to the list of directories to be searched for header files.

You can use the `pkg-config` to get proper flags:

```
$:pkg-config QtCore --cflags
-DQT_SHARED -I/usr/include/qt4 -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore
```

For linking:

```
$:pkg-config QtCore --libs
-lQtCore
```

You can use `pkg-config` when calling the compiler:

```
g++ test.cpp `pkg-config QtCore --cflags --libs`
```

or

```
g++ `pkg-config QtCore --cflags` test.cpp `pkg-config QtCore --libs`
```

Note that the following way won't work:

```
g++ `pkg-config QtCore --cflags --libs` test.cpp
```